# VHDL output is undifined in simulation but compilation is passed fine

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am a fresh student and the assignment is to build 3 components with testbench and then to arrange them into one structure. All 3 components I have built work great but when I put them together one of the the outputs stays undefined. I tried to trace the signal called `dat` and it is fine, but probably I am not using correct syntax to assign the `dat` signal to `data_out` . The `id_led_ind` is the second output and it works fine but the `data_out` is undefined.

Here is the code **(i think the problem is in lane 21 - "data_out <= dat")**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity peak_detect is
  port(
    input      : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    data_out   : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    reset      : in  std_logic;
    clock      : in  std_logic;
    enable     : in  std_logic;
    id_led_ind : out std_logic);
end peak_detect;

architecture dataflow of peak_detect is
  signal a_big_b : std_logic;
  signal en      : std_logic;
  signal dat     : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
  en       <= (enable or a_big_b);
  data_out <= dat;
end dataflow;

architecture structure of peak_detect is
  signal a_big_b : std_logic;
  signal en      : std_logic;
  signal dat     : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

  component comp_8bit is
    port(
      A   : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      B   : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      res : out std_logic);
  end component;

  component dff is
    port (
      data  : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      q     : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      clk   : in  std_logic;
      reset : in  std_logic;
      en    : in  std_logic);
  end component;

  component id_sens is
    port(
      data_in : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
      led     : out std_logic);
  end component;

begin
  reg  : dff port map (data => input, q => dat, clk => clock, reset => reset, en => enable);
  comp : comp_8bit port map (A => input, B => dat, res => a_big_b);
  sens : id_sens port map (data_in => dat, led => id_led_ind);
end structure;
```

Comment: In the dataflow architecture, what drives "dat"?

Comment: Barring command line specification of the architecture and in the absence of a configuration specification the last analyzed architecture will be selected, which in this case would be the architecture structure of peak_detect.  If dataflow offends thee, comment it out.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be confusion over having two architectures (dataflow and structure) for the entity peak_detect.  The two architectures are  mutually exclusive, and the last one analyzed is the default in absence of other configuration specifying one of the architectures directly.

For purposes of evaluating how the components are interconnected and their port mapped connections relate to the port declarations of peak_detect, the first architecture could be commented out (dataflow).

When you disregard the architecture dataflow we find there is no driver for data_out in architecture structure.

You're missing an assignment to data_out using dat as a source in architecture structure, as found in architecture dataflow.  Copy  or replicate the concurrent signal assignment statement data_out <= dat; into architecture structure.

You can't simply connect data_out to q in the port map of dff because the output of dff is also used as an input to id_sense.

Answer (score 0):

`dat` is driven by `q` of `dff`. That is not how you connect components. `port map` should be used to connect ports of different components/entities, not signals of any entity to the port of another entity.

Comment: dat is a declared signal in the architecture structure of peak_detect.  It's perfectly okay to connect a signal as an actual to a formal in a port map when they are the same type with the same range (the subtypes match).  What's missing in the connection from dat to data_out in the port declaration for entity peak_detect.

Comment: It might be "perfectly okay" for the compiler/simulator, but when it comes to humans trying to read, understand and debug, its far from perfect. Why not put all the logic in one entity then? Tools will be all right with that.

Comment: It appears you are trying to enforce style as opposed to specifying compliance with the VHDL standard.

Comment: Style doesn't necessarily exclude compliance. At least mine dosn't.

Comment: The standard doesn't embrace your style as required. Note "You can't simply connect data_out to q in the port map of dff because the output of dff is also used as an input to id_sense.", see IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.2 Interface object declarations,Para 18 "- out. The value of the interface object is allowed to be updated and, provided it is not a signal parameter, read." peak_detect port signal data_out is declared mode out and can't be used as an actual in comp8bit association list formal port B mode in - signal parameter data_out can't be read (Para 15). See also -1993, 4.3.2 Para 12/10.

Comment: Agreed. I was confused with there being two architectures: dataflow and structure, both declaring dat signal, until I read your answer. Go ahead and down-vote.